# aligning multiple labels below xaxis using matplotlib at equi-distances

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a few labels below the x-axis using matplotlib.  I have 5-6 labels which I want to plot below the xaxis.  The text of these labels will vary hence, having a single setting to render the labels is not possible.  I have a minimal example given below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate sample data

frame_width = 1920
frame_height =1080 

##plotting function begins
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(frame_width/100,frame_height/100))

ax = plt.gca()
fig = plt.gcf()
fig_width = fig.get_figwidth() * fig.dpi

txtcolor='White'
text_font_size=12
textfont='Arial'

# Show only the x-axis
ax.set_xlim(1, 20)

txt1="ATTENTION"
a1 = plt.figtext(0.15, 0.070, txt1, ha='left',va='center',weight='bold',c=txtcolor,family=textfont ,fontsize=text_font_size, bbox=dict(facecolor='g', edgecolor='g'))
txt1_width = a1.get_window_extent().width / fig_width
txt2_x = txt1_width + 0.15 + 0.02 

txt2="CONVICTION"
a2=plt.figtext(txt2_x, 0.070, txt2, ha='left',va='center',weight='bold',c=txtcolor,family=textfont ,fontsize=text_font_size, bbox=dict(facecolor='c', edgecolor='c'))
txt2_width = a2.get_window_extent().width / fig_width
txt3_x = txt2_width + 0.15 + 0.03 + txt1_width

txt3="INTEREST IN SPORTS"
a3=plt.figtext(txt3_x, 0.070, txt3, ha='left',va='center',weight='bold',c=txtcolor,family=textfont ,fontsize=text_font_size, bbox=dict(facecolor='m', edgecolor='m'))
txt3_width = a3.get_window_extent().width / fig_width
txt4_x = txt2_width + 0.15 + 0.03 + txt1_width + txt3_width

plt.show()
```

I am trying to take the width of the text + add a padding so that the next text does not overlap.  However, as the text varies in length, I have to change the setting to avoid overlapping or creating a larger gap between the text labels.  How can I dynamically render it so that the text labels look uniformly spaced irrespective of the size of the text.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? What does your plot look like? If it's a bar plot then you can have text labels for each bar.

Comment: @jared no it is not a xy problem.  The plot is a animated line graph with multiple lines differentiated by their color.  The labels are positioned as a surrogate to the legend to make the chart look good.  The solution that I have drawn does plot the labels in the intended position.  However not aligning itself to a dynamically drawn text.  Had it been a bar plot, I could have printed the labels inside the bar at 90 degree angle. or would have modified the xticks

Comment: You prefer to place the labels as text objects rather than have a legend outside of the plot?

Comment: Yes.  because the line chart is to be embedded on a video and I want it to be minimal.  I tried plt.annotate - have the same issue.

Comment: One idea is to put them to the right. There, you only have to worry about the heights, which should be consistent, and you leave room for an x-axis label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `annotate`, you can place text relative to any other artist, including another annotation.  Here I place the first text relative to the axes.  Subsequent annotations are placed by putting the text 1.5 font sizes (`xytext=(1.5, 0)`) to the right of the righthand side of the previous annotation (`xy=(1, 0)`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate sample data

frame_width = 1920
frame_height =1080 

##plotting function begins
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(frame_width/100,frame_height/100))

ax = plt.gca()
fig = plt.gcf()
fig_width = fig.get_figwidth() * fig.dpi

txtcolor='White'
text_font_size=12
textfont='Arial'

# Show only the x-axis
ax.set_xlim(1, 20)

txt1="ATTENTION"
ann = ax.annotate(txt1, (0, -0.1), ha='left',va='center',weight='bold',
                  c=txtcolor, family=textfont, fontsize=text_font_size,
                  xycoords='axes fraction',
                  bbox=dict(facecolor='g', edgecolor='g'))

for txt, color in zip(["CONVICTION", "INTEREST IN SPORTS"], ['c', 'm']):
    ann = ax.annotate(txt, (1, 0.5), xycoords=ann, xytext=(1.5, 0), 
                      textcoords='offset fontsize', va='center', weight='bold',
                      c=txtcolor, family=textfont, fontsize=text_font_size,
                      bbox=dict(facecolor=color, edgecolor=color))

plt.show()
```

[image]